# npm install removes react router from package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router

When I delete node_modules from my app, and then run npm install, my package-lock.json is changed and react-router is removed from it. I am getting errors that module react-router is not found. Before it was working perfectly. Here is my webpack-config:

```
`module.exports = {
  entry: ['whatwg-fetch', "./js/app.jsx"],
  output: { filename: "./js/out.js" },
  watch: true,
  devServer: {
  inline: true,
  contentBase: './',
  port: 3001
  },
  module: {
  loaders: [
      {
      test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: { presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react'] }
      },
      {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}`
```

and my package.json

```
`{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely just installed `react-router-dom` without adding it to your `dependencies` before you deleted your `node_modules`. Try to install it and add it to your `dependencies`, and it will work again.

```
npm i -S react-router-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

React router dom is uninstalled due to you deleted the node_modules, so you have to re-install the react-router

1. npm install --save react-router-dom